# redirect to a other view in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that runs on a click, I want this click to redirect to a other view. like a simple link.

how can I render a new view onclick?

node

```
router.post('/shareinsight', function(req, res, next) {
    console.dir(req.body)
    var db = req.db_login;
    console.log('fs' + req.body.date)
    res.redirect('contact');
});
```

I can see the log in the console so I know that the function is running but it doesn't change view

Comment: try this `res.redirect('/contact')`

Comment: what do you see in the Chrome Developer Tool>Network tab? Are you using AJAX request in the front-end for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
router.post('/shareinsight', function(req, res, next) {
    console.dir(req.body)
    var db = req.db_login;
    console.log('fs' + req.body.date)
    res.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'url'
});
res.end();
});
```